# Android click and touch events not working properly

Tags: android

Actually i have an activity that downloads data from server and that  data contains lattitude ,longitude and images of various venues, this images are downloaded from server and shown in listview and on same activity i am showing listview and mapview alternatively , by hiding the listview and mapview respectively.I am getting this error 
bimap size exceeds Virtual memory

For this i simply added try-catch statement but  On clicking listview, my clickevents are responding very late and my application is forced close without showing any error in Logcat.

Answer (score 1):

Your app is closing abruptly since it is not having enough memory. Look for some other alternative. I can suggest an option. Use menu on both map & listView and use them to switch to each other.

Answer (score 1):

just use lazy image downloading from server or load image in background process(async task)

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this google example to learn more on, how to handle out-of-memory exception.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Your application is not responding because of out of memory.

I hope this url will be helpful to you.